# Adding items in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I have problems with my list . I had an Activity I get some Data from.

The data must accessed in variables in my class :

**Mylist.java class**

```
public  String Job,Ship,Location,Shift,Date;
   public String workingHour;
    Mylist(String job,String loc,String shp,String shft,String dat,String wh){
        Job=job;
        Location=loc;
        Ship=shp;
        Shift=shft;
        Date=dat;
        workingHour=wh;
    }
```

and by pressing Save Button The list must add an item.My problem is when I add another items the list have only one item How to fix this ?

Adding Class :

**AddOredit.java**

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_oredit);

        final ArrayList<Mylist>list =new ArrayList<>();
        final ArrayList<String> Job=new ArrayList<>();

         String selecteditem1, selecteditem2,getlocation,getship,getdate,gethours;

 Spinner type=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.s1);
        Spinner shift=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.s2);

        EditText location=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.loc);
        EditText ship=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ship);
        EditText date=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.date);
        EditText workinghours=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.hours);

        Button Save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editbtn);
        Button cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelbtn);

        selecteditem1 = type.getSelectedItem().toString(); //for first spinner
        selecteditem2 = shift.getSelectedItem().toString();//for second spinner

          getlocation=location.getText().toString();
          getship=ship.getText().toString();
          getdate=date.getText().toString();
         gethours=workinghours.getText().toString();

list.add(new Mylist(selecteditem1,getlocation,getship,selecteditem2,getdate,gethours));
        Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(list.size()));
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
            Job.add("Job "+(i+1));
        }
 //When pressing save Button

        Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //list.add(new Mylist(selecteditem1, getlocation, getship, selecteditem2, getdate, gethours));



                Intent intent = new Intent(AddOredit.this, MainActivity.class);

                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("MyList", Job);


                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

}
```

**MainActivity.java** this class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    Button ADD=(Button)findViewById(R.id.addbtn);
    Button DELETE=(Button)findViewById(R.id.deletebtn);
    Button PROFILE=(Button)findViewById(R.id.profilebtn);
    Intent intent=getIntent();

    ArrayList<String> Job ;
    Job=intent.getStringArrayListExtra("MyList");

    if(Job!=null){

        ListAdapter adapter= new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Job);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);



        //when user click on add button
    }
    ADD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //go to AddOreditpage
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddOredit.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

**Note :- ** Add Button is for Adding items in the list and Save Button is for saving data entered at AddOredit class.

**Note :- ** By clicking Add Button , getting to the AddOredit Activity .
By Clicking Save Button, getting back to the main activity with the item added

Comment: Sorry about that , but I'm a new member . I didn't have much knowledge about that .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning a new List for list object on your second activity created. Try to assign the list with an existing object and add your new object.

EDIT:
Try to Declare this globally as,

private static ArrayList list =new ArrayList<>();

and with in onCreate() remove it. Let me know if it still do not work.

Comment: Could you please update the code with your recent code?

Comment: Mylist l=new Mylist(selecteditem1,getlocation,getship,selecteditem2,getdate,gethours);
list.add(l);